# Unknow column 'r.Concurrency Stamp'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible for me to generate the concurrency stamp by manual? Because the existing database doesn't has any data match with the concurrency stamp column. Or can I edit the Identity User inside the metadata?

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>{public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }}
```

Comment: For me, It's not clear what you are asking...

Comment: sorry, is it possible for me not to generate the concurrency stamp by default since I don't need the feature, haha.